# DateOnly.ParseExact incorrect parsing

Tags: c#, .net

I believe there is a flaw in  DateOnly.ParseExact. Refer following example. All the output dates should be same.

```
namespace IssueRep1
{
    internal class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        { string[] formats = { "dd/mm/yyyy" };
            string format = formats[0];
            string _strDate = "01/08/2014";
            DateOnly _do1 = DateOnly.ParseExact(_strDate, formats);
            DateOnly _do2 = DateOnly.ParseExact(_strDate, format);
            Console.WriteLine($"{_strDate}, {_do1} {_do2}");
        }
    }
}
```

output
`01/08/2014, 01-01-2014 01-01-2014`

I expected all dates to be equal. August month is being converted to Jan. Can you please confirm if it is a bug or something is wrong with my understanding? How can I file a bug report in dotnet library?

Answer (score 4):

What you should use is

```
string[] formats = { "dd/MM/yyyy" };
```

The format of month is `MM` not `mm` the lower case `m` is for minute and this is the `datetime` format [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/custom-date-and-time-format-strings)